# Output error dynamically allocating class objects into a queue template

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "QueueAr.h"

class Test { 

        int val;
    public: 
        Test(int v) 
        {val = v;};  

        int  getVal() 
        {return val;};  

}; 

using namespace std; 
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 

    Queue<Test*> testStack(4); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        Test *t = new Test(5); 
        testStack.enqueue(t); 
        delete t; 
    } 

    while(!testStack.isEmpty()) 
        cout << (testStack.dequeue())->getVal()  << endl;


return 0; 
}
```

So I'm trying to play with the idea of declaring a template class with a data type that is programmer-defined. I decided to go a queue implementation made by the author of my data structures book as the template class.

Now I'm trying to feed some values into it.

I started by creating a Queue object whose data type is a pointer variable to my own class Test. I used a pointer variable because `Queue<Test>` wasn't working properly for some reason. Next, I came up with the above for loop to make an attempt at initializing, but when I dequeue and display the values, it returns all of them as zero, despite sending 5 to Test's constructor four times in the loop. I believe it might have something to do with the loop, or Test*, but I'm not entirely sure.

Does anyone know what might be wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Also, if anyone needs it, here are the links for the header file "QueueAr.h" and its member functions

https://github.com/rweichler/ecs60/blob/master/p2/src/QueueAr.h

https://github.com/rweichler/ecs60/blob/master/p2/src/QueueAr.cpp

Answer (score 1):

After storing the pointer to `Test` in your `Queue` you delete the pointer.   This frees the memory and leaves the pointer stored in the `Queue` dangling, pointing at freed memory.  When you dereference this pointer to display the value you can get anything.